# InstagramAPi install error with decorator version

Tags: python, instagram-api

While running `pip install InstagramAPI` im getting the following error.

> "networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have
>   decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible"

So I uninstalled decorator and reinstalled it using `pip install decorator==4.1.0`. I confirmed with `pip list` the version of decorator. I then tried to `pip install InstagramApi` I got the same error

> "networkx 2.1 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have
>   decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible."

and my decorator module was regressed to version 4.0.11!!!

Someone please explain whats going on here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a virtual python environment (the python package) It should take care of these Dependency problems.